# How to query for a List<String> in JdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I'm using Spring's `JdbcTemplate` and running a query like this:

```
SELECT COLNAME FROM TABLEA GROUP BY COLNAME
```

There are no named parameters being passed, however, column name, `COLNAME`, will be passed by the user.

**Questions**

1. Is there a way to have placeholders, like `?` for column names? For example `SELECT ? FROM TABLEA GROUP BY ?`
2. If I want to simply run the above query and get a `List<String>` what is the best way?

Currently I'm doing:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> data = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(query);
for (Map m : data) {
  System.out.println(m.get("COLNAME"));
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Is there a way to have placeholders, like ? for column names? For example SELECT ? FROM TABLEA GROUP BY ?

Use dynamic query as below:

```
String queryString = "SELECT "+ colName+ " FROM TABLEA GROUP BY "+ colName;
```

> If I want to simply run the above query and get a List what is the best way?

```
List<String> data = getJdbcTemplate().query(query, new RowMapper<String>(){
                            public String mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) 
                                                         throws SQLException {
                                    return rs.getString(1);
                            }
                       });
```

EDIT: To Stop SQL Injection, check for non word characters in the colName as :

```
          Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\W");
          if(pattern.matcher(str).find()){
               //throw exception as invalid column name
          }
```

Comment: In using dynamic query I'll be putting whatever the user enters into my dynamic query which is a scary part.

Comment: @birdy: You may want to check the string has only `word characters` by using a simple regex `\\w`. That will prevent any sql injection possibility.

Comment: You should use prepared statements instead of doing this regex stuff. Try this: ```getJdbcTemplate().query("SELECT ? FROM TABLEA GROUP BY ?", new RowMapper<String>(){
                            public String mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) 
                                                         throws SQLException {
                                    return rs.getString(1);
                            }
                       }, colName, colName);```

Comment: how we will map the rows if we have more than one argument.. ie.. in the place of columnName

Comment: With lambda you can use this:
List<String> data = getJdbcTemplate().query(query, (rs, rowNum) -> rs.getString(1));

Answer (score 114):

To populate a List of String, you need not use custom row mapper. Implement it using `queryForList`.

```
List<String>data=jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query,String.class)
```

Answer (score 24):

Use following code

`List data = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(query,String.class)`

Comment: This is working fine. Going forward, how can I pass values if query has *IN operator* to this ? Please assist! The values are List<BigInteger> inside In operator

Answer (score 1):

You can't use placeholders for column names, table names, data type names, or basically anything that isn't data.