# How to query for a single column in NamedJdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

How do I query for a List of Integers using namedParameterJdbcTemplate? I tried following this template, it is not working below .

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40417349/15435022

```
String customerName = "JOE";
MapSqlParameterSource customerParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
customerParameters.addValue("CustomerName", customerName);

private static final String query = "SELECT Customer_Id From dbo.Customers WHERE Customer_Name = :CustomerName";

List<Integer> data = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, Integer.class);
```

> Error: Cannot resolve method 'queryForList(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class<java.lang.Integer>)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why code gives an error

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) *queryForList* Method have following implementations available:

1. `queryForList(String sql, Map<String,?> paramMap)`.
2. `queryForList(String sql, Map<String,?> paramMap, Class<T> elementType)`
3. `queryForList(String sql, SqlParameterSource paramSource)`
4. `queryForList(String sql, SqlParameterSource paramSource, Class<T> elementType)`

None of these implementations matches the parameters used in the given implementation. Thus, we end up with this error:

> Error: Cannot resolve method 'queryForList(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class<java.lang.Integer>)'

### The idea behind passing missing parameter

The key idea behind passing a *Map* or *ParameterSource* is to have a dynamic query where we can put in values later on.

Eg:

```
    String query = "Select :columnName from table";
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();  
    map.put("columnName", "userName");
```

When this map is passed along with the *query* *String*, internally it is used to replace placeholders with the values from the map.

### How to fix the code

There are two ways you can fix this:

1. **Just pass ***null*****

This is not the best way of fixing the problem is definitely not recommended for a production code. But, this can be used if there is no placeholder in the query string.
Code:

```
List<Integer> data = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, null, Integer.class);
```

2. **Create and pass an empty *Map* or *SqlParameterSource***

You already have a *MapSqlParameterSource* called *customerParameters* in your code. Simply pass it while calling *queryForList()*
Code:

```
List<Integer> data = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, customerParameters, Integer.class);
```

Comment: i got around passing params like this. i just appended the id to the query and passed in an empty SqlParameterSource like akash mentioned. thank you akash.

`Integer statusCode= namedParamJdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT STATUS_CODE FROM STATUS WHERE ID = 1234", new MapSqlParameterSource(), Integer.class).stream().collect(Collectors.toList()).stream().findFirst().orElse(0);`