# Equivalent of Number(38) in Oracle DB SQL?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am trying to get Oracle SQL Data into Java JBDC.

What is the Java convert data type equivalent of `Number(38)` in Oracle? Is it `BigInteger` or `Long`?

```
create table Customers
(
    Customer_id                   NUMBER(38)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`long` is not enough. It only have 19 decimals:

> Maximum value = [2^63-1 = 9,223,372,036,854,775,807](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E63-1).

You need to use `BigInteger`. `BigDecimal` should also be fine.

Comment: Or `BigDecimal`?

Comment: I don't see BigInteger in the result set mapper below, rs,  would BigDecimal work also?            List<BigInteger> customerIdList  = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(GET_CUSTOMER_ID_QUERY, (rs, rowNum) -> rs.get..  , related question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68884237/how-to-query-for-a-listinteger-in-jdbctemplate

Comment: cc @andrewjames comment above

Comment: @andrewjames you can, but AFAIR if you don't specify number of digits after decimal point it is considered 0.

Comment: @talex Yes, the scale (2nd argument) defaults to 0, so `NUMBER( 38 )` is effectively a whole number (no fraction).  See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT313).

Comment: I corrected your number from 18 digits to 19, per my calculations of [`Long.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE). Am I right?

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes, 18 whole. If you use 19 you won't be able to convert all possible values from `long` to JDBC. If you use 18 you can't convert from JDBC to `long`. Chose wisely :)

Comment: I shouldn't even use long in the first place, just having a row mapping issue, seems getBigDecimal is utilized in resultset. , get BigInteger isn't ? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68884237/how-to-query-for-a-listinteger-in-jdbctemplate

Comment: @mattsmith5 If supported, it is `getObject(<idx/name>, BigInteger.class)`. Unfortunately, the JDBC specification is not very clear on `BigInteger` support, so this may vary between JDBC drivers. The specific `getXXX` methods are a hold-over from older, pre-generics, design decisions and are no longer added for newer types.